# How to find the Entry Point in the Magento project version 1.9.3.1

Tags: entry-point

I am unable to find the entry point in the project where my index.php is located in the project, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Index.php  file always exists in root of your Magento.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1.9.3.1 or any version of magento index.php is found in your root folder without index.php magento not run you can find publichtml or var/www/projectname/ if your in localhost xampp htdocs/project name or wamp www/your project name.